# Manipulating SurfaceScrollViewer content

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I'm diving into WPF here and I can't figure some things with multitouch.
I've got two questions about SurfaceScrollViewer.

Easier one first: I've got a large photo I'm displaying with SurfaceScrollViewer, so I can pan around, but I can't figure out how to get the content to start out centered in the screen.  I can't find any native alignment properties in SScrollViewer. If I give the content margins, it crops it.  Same if I do a RenderTransform. If I do a LayoutTransform, it doesn't seem to do change.   Any ideas?

I also want to give this content Zoom functionality while inside SurfaceScrollViewer. Really I'm trying to zoom and pan with the elastic effects of SSV.  Should I write the manipulations out by hand or can I patch the functions in SSV to be able to zoom?  It seems like SSV absorbs 2nd touches into its panning function.  I'd have to write a Manipulation handler to send multi touches to the content, right?

My code looks something like this right now:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid"  Width="1950" Height="1118" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >
       <s:SurfaceScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >

            <local:FloorView  x:Name="floorViewer" Width="4209" Height="1442"  >
            <local:FloorView.LayoutTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="1000" />
            </local:FloorView.LayoutTransform>
        </local:FloorView>
       </s:SurfaceScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

figured out the first part:

```
scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(x);
scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(y);
```

looks like i'll have to control manipulation events on the SSV to add zoom.

Answer (score 0):

figured out the second part to zoom inside scrollviewer

- handle touchdown events on the scrollviewer
- send one touches to surfacescrollviewer and
- send two touches to the content
- enable manipulations on content
- handle manipulations with the scrollviewer as the container
- then use the delta manipulations to add a ScaleTransform to the content
- don't forget to handle touchup events

  ```
  private void floorViewer_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)  //catch touch events on floorviewer
  {

      Touch1ID = e.TouchDevice.Id - 16777216; ;

      if (Touch1ID == 0)  //if one touch present, TouchDevice.Id is 2^24, two then 2^24+1 (this might just be my machine)
      {
          floorViewer.IsManipulationEnabled = false;
          floorViewer.ReleaseTouchCapture(e.TouchDevice);
          scrollViewer.CaptureTouch(e.TouchDevice);
      }
      else {
          floorViewer.IsManipulationEnabled = true;
          foreach(TouchDevice device in scrollViewer.TouchesOver){
          scrollViewer.ReleaseTouchCapture(device);
          floorViewer.CaptureTouch(device);
          }
      }
      StartTimeout();
      e.Handled = true;
  }

  void scrollViewer_TouchUp(object sender,TouchEventArgs e)
  {
      clearID();
      e.Handled = true;
  }

  private void clearID()
  {
      Touch1ID = 0;
  }

  private void floorview_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
  {
      clearID();
      e.Handled = true;
  }

  //manipulators on floorviewer when it gets touches passed to it
  private void scrollViewer_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
  {
      e.ManipulationContainer = scrollViewer;
      e.Handled = true;
  }

  private void scrollViewer_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
  {
      double oldScale = flrScale;
      flrScale *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
      if (flrScale < .95 | flrScale > 2) flrScale = oldScale;
      floorViewer.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(flrScale, flrScale, e.ManipulationOrigin.X + flrInitX, e.ManipulationOrigin.Y + flrInitY);


      e.Handled = true;
  }
  ```

  boom!

Comment: obviously shouldve been a LayoutTransform not a RenderTransform! to avoid cropping